# Show hidden (.files) in AndroidStudio's Device File Explorer

Tags: android-studio, explorer, hidden-files

In a project we have a "hidden" folder (a folder which name starts with a '.') on the device. Accessing it from Code is no Problem, but in AndroidStudios "Device File Explorer" I cannot find an option that displays unix hidden files. 
Using adb shell is very annoying.

Is there an Option (maybe hidden somewhere) in AndroidStudios "Device File Explorer" to make them visible? I can't manage to find it.

If not, is there an "AndroidStudio feature proposal" page where I can ask to add that feature?

Comment: I have this same problem, so for what it's worth, I haven't found a solution. There is a keybinding called "Show Hidden Files and Directories", but when I bind it to a key and use it in the Device File Explorer, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: At least we have a bug report now ;) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140057005

Comment: Thank you for filing a bug report!

Comment: Here we are in 2021, still missing a basic feature.

Comment: Still can't find anything. Is the feature ever implemented?

Comment: @Saar should be in the Android Studio Chipmunk release... finally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Android Studio Chipmunk.
The project explorer shows up all the hidden files startng with "." .

Comment: yeah... it got finally resolved...